# Rails rendering, it doesn't show the same url as before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

I have a problem getting render to work, my path is

```
/dashboard/models/new
```

If the verification fails, it's supposed to render that page using

```
render :new
```

, but the url changes to

```
/models/new
```

Without proper layout. Using

```
render :new, :layout => 'dashboard'
```

brings the layout back, but not the path.

My routes.rb

```
match '/dashboard' => 'home#dashboard', as: :dashboard_home
scope '/dashboard' do
    resources :models, only: :new
end
root :to => 'home#index'
```

Any one can help me with this? 
Thanks in advance

---

My controller has a lot of code, the part that makes this is :

```
if model.save
    redirect_to "/dashboard/#{@model_type.to_s.downcase}s"
else
    flash.now[:error] = model.error.messages[:title]
    render :new, :layout => "dashboard"
end
```

Comment: can you post your controller code please?

Comment: @Alex, I've edited it with that part of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to used namespace instead.

you route file will look like this

```
namespace :dashboard do
  resources :models, :only => :new
end
```

and in form_for tag you should send namespace to it like this

```
<%= form_for [:dashboard, @model] do |f| %>
```

Not sure is this answers your questions.

Comment: I've tried your code Boat, But I couldn't make it work, probably my own lack of understanding. It said there's no constant named Dashboard.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to told you that your controller should be in controllers/dashboard/models_controller.rb and named Dashboard::ModelsController